# If $u\in L^\infty$, does the inequality $\int_\mathbb R u(x) |v(x)|^2 dx\le \|u\|_{L^\infty} \int_\mathbb R |v(x)|^2 dx$ hold true?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $u, v:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^3$. Suppose that $u\in L^\infty(\mathbb R, \mathbb R^3)$ and $v\in L^2(\mathbb R, \mathbb R^3)$.

Consider the integral
$$\int_\mathbb R u(x) |v(x)|^2 dx.$$

The question is that if I can say that
$$\int_\mathbb R u(x) |v(x)|^2 dx\le \|u\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R, \mathbb R^3)} \int_\mathbb R |v(x)|^2 dx = \|u\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R, \mathbb R^3)} \|v\|_{L^2(\mathbb R, \mathbb R^3)}.$$

I wrote this in an exercise of my last test, but I was warned that the first inequality is wrong.
I can not see why.

Anyone could please help me in understanding this?

Comment: The first inequality is correct, not wrong.

Comment: Your estimate is 
$$
\text{some 3D-vector}\leq \text{some scalar value} =\text{some scalar value}.
$$
The dimensions don't match - even if your estimate was intended to be e.g. componentwise.